# No. entries between two dates in excel/google spreadsheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Bit of a beginner with excel and GS, but I need to input a formula to count the number of entries between two dates. Moreover, I need to be able to understand it, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is in columns A:B like so:

```
1/1/2015    a
1/2/2015    b
1/3/2015    c
1/4/2015    d
1/5/2015    e
1/6/2015    f
1/7/2015    g
1/8/2015    h
1/9/2015    i
1/10/2015   j
1/11/2015   k
```

And start and end dates are in cells D1 and E1, respectively.

Excel Formula Is `=COUNTIFS(A1:A11,">="&D1,A1:A11,"<="&E1)`

Google Spreadsheet Is `=COUNTA(FILTER(B:B;A:A>=D1;A:A<=E1))`

For more on this topic see links for [Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842) and [Google Spreadsheet](http://spreadsheetpro.net/how-to-make-sumifs-countifs-averagifs-functions-in-google-spreadsheet/)